# Update the source Dataset of Azure Data factory built-in copy task

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am new to Azure Data Lakes. Currently I am using **ADLS Gen2**. I have configured pipelines for single source data sets to destination data sets. This is working fine.
Then I configured the pipeline for uploading / ingesting whole database from on-prem to ADLS gen2.

Here is the process:
Factory studio -> Ingest -> Built-in copy task -> sql server as Data store and configured runtime -> Select All tables (Existing tables) -> and so on.

Then from pipelines when I trigger this activity, it successfully uploads all tables to containers in separate files(based on source table names)

Then when I update data in one of the tables in sources it successfully updates the data in destination file.

But the problem is when I add new table in database and then triggers the activity, this new table is not uploaded. Is there a way to update source data set to include this new table?

I have seen all the properties of source data set and activity in pipeline. Also searched for the solution, but stuck in this scenario.

Comment: `when I update data in one of the tables in sources it successfully updates the data in destination file`. When you update the tables, are you running the pipeline again?

Comment: Yes, I rerun the pipeline, Is there a way to get updated schema?

Comment: The pipeline has pre-built parameter for table names and hence even when you add new tables to database, this parameters value is not changing and hence it won't be copied to ADLS

Comment: Yeah, exactly the problem I'm facing. Is there a way to change it dynamically or any other way by which I can set my pipeline so that it tracks new changes in the database..

Comment: If you database is Sql Server use a Lookup activity with SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' as the query to get all the tables.  If another database then there should be similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically get list of all tables and copy it to your datalake storage account, you can use the following procedure:

I have used a script activity on my azure SQL database (for demonstration) to get the list of tables in my database using the following query as suggested by **@Scott Mildenberger**:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

[image]

- Now in `for each` loop, Use items value as the output rows of above script activity i.e., `@activity('get tables').output.resultSets[0].rows`. Inside for each loop, use a copy activity, where source is your database and destination is ADLS sink.
- I have created 2 parameters for sink destination called `schema` and `table` and used them as shown below:

[image]

- In the source settings of copy activity, I have given the values for these dataset parameters as following:

```
schema: @item().TABLE_SCHEMA
table: @item().TABLE_NAME
```

[image]

- For ADLS sink, I have created 2 parameters called `schema` and `table` and I have used it to create file name dynamically as `@{dataset().schema}@{dataset().table}.csv`.

[image]

- I have given its values in sink settings of copy data same as above.

[image]

- When I run the pipeline, it will give desired results. The following is a reference image. Even when you add a new table, the query will pick this up and copy it as a file to your ADLS container.

[image]

Comment: Right on the mark, Worked perfectly.